# (Swift 4.x+) What are the rules for naming parameters in structs’ initializers?

Tags: struct, parameters, swift4, naming-conventions, initializer

I have been doing an intense - yet basic apparently - study on structs in these last days and one of the things I cannot understand is why one would ever name parameters in an initializer differently from their original name.

I know that is possible, that it is allowed but, in practice, I have always seen *shadowing* instead.

For example:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(firstName: String, ancientness: Int) {
        self.name = firstName
        self.age = ancientness
    }
}
```

Apart from the absurd fun one would have in inventing idiotic names, is there a truly practical reason why one would ever do such a thing?

Thank you

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you! The tutorial I was following had plenty of these variations. When I asked the author why was this he simply answered that “code is full of variations”. I nevertheless found it very confusing. If there is a longer explanation please point me to it if you can.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you so much, this is much clearer!

Comment: @LeoDabus yes please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The long answer is when creating a custom structure you don't even have to provide a custom initializer. The struct will provide it for you. Not related to your question but you should always declare your properties as constants. If you need a different value create a new structure with the values updated from the old instance. Just create a "plain" structure:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int 
}
```

This will provide a the default initializer with the following signature:

```
Person.init(name: String, age: Int)
```

If you were gonna provide yourself the same initializer for that structure it would be written as:

```
init(name: String, age: Int) { 
    self.name = name
    self.age = age 
}
```

the final thoughts

There is no reason to do such thing. You should keep your initializers names matching the name of the properties that they will be assigned to. The only "advantage" of choosing a different name is not having to explicitly call `self` inside the initializer.

In your example it would suffice

```
init(firstName: String, ancientness: Int) {
    name = firstName
    age = ancientness
}
```

but not on mine

```
init(name: String, age: Int) {
    name = name  // Cannot assign to value: 'name' is a 'let' constant
    age = age    // Cannot assign to value: 'name' is a 'let' constant
}
```

A Truly practical reason?

The only one I can see is dropping the `self` which can already be done 99% of the time already when coding in Swift. I actually like a lot to use the shadowing whenever it is possible in all of my answers. You can see it at this post [Swift Array instance method drop(at: Int)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358273/2303865) where a local var `index`shadowing the collection method `index<T: Comparable>(_ T, offsetBy: T, limitedBy: T)`.

Or at this post [Swift: second occurrence with indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972688/swift-second-occurrence-with-indexof/34972814#34972814) a classic shadowing example

```
var startIndex = self.startIndex
```

Where you can refer to `startIndex` local method variable or the collection's instance property adding the self prefix `self.startIndex`.